# AS3 Get Functions

Tags: actionscript-3

So I've got an AS3 AS file with a function like this:

```
    static function get instance() {
        if (__instance == null) {
            __instance = new com.disney.dlearning.managers.DLSManager();
        }
        return(__instance);
    }
```

In another AS file, I got to call it like this:

```
   function phoneClosing()
   {
   if(this.__isOpen)
  {
     this.__isOpen = false;
     com.disney.dlearning.managers.DLSManager.__get__instance().pushOpcodeToHost(com.disney.dlearning.client.phone.DLearning.HOST,"STOP",com.disney.dlearning.client.phone.DLearning.CP_SPY_PHONE,this.dlsmCallback,"","","","");
  }
```

}

And every time I get an error like this:
C:\Users\USername\CPSWF\Flippr AS3\Client\interface\com\disney\dlearning\client\phone\DLearning.as, Line 31 There is no method with the name '__get__instance'.

How can I successfully call this function? It seems I likely just need to know what to put instead of __get__instance. Thanks,
-Sandor

Comment: `.instance` ? i mean, that's the name of the method...and maybe put `public` before you declare it if you want to access it from outside the package

Comment: This question is probably an NDA violation in it's current form.

Comment: Is this decompiled code?

Comment: First of all, use imports instead of typing full class name. Secondly, when you use get/set function you need to call it by name (without keyword set/get): `var instance = obj.instance()`

Comment: As Marton said, methods with the `get` keyword are accessed just like public fields, no parenthesis needed. However, this does seem very much like decompiled code. OP, working with decompiled code is not fun let alone ethical. I'd recommend writing for yourself whatever code you need, it will be cleaner, clearer, and legaler.

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't decompiled. A colleague sent it to me asking if could fix it, but it was beyond my scope. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need to call is com.disney.dlearning.managers.DLSManager.instance to access that singleton. I did AS3 programming for three years but its been a while so I could be wrong...